# second maximum fees

Tags: sql, rownum

Write a query to display Course ID and course name of the course which has a second maximum fee. If there are more than two courses then sort it by using Course ID.

[image]

I tried using the limit function but it's not working this is the help they have given
"MySQL supports the LIMIT clause" to select a limited number of records, while Oracle uses ROWNUM. ROWNUM, however, has limitations as in you can not fetch a particular row of your choice except row1. 
Since you are on oracle, please write an inner subquery (say s1) that returns the max fees. Write an outer subquery (say s2) too that returns the max fees. s2 != s1 will return the second max. 
Do try this logic and feel free to get back for clarifications, if any.

Comment: Can you please clarify this statement `ROWNUM, however has limitations as in you can not a fetch a particular row of your choice except row1. ` ?

Comment: i need to select rows which have second maximum fees

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic. This will only work if there are Unique Fees available for each course.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT courseid,courseName,Fees
    FROM Course
    ORDER BY Fees DESC
    LIMIT 2 
) A
ORDER BY Fees
LIMIT 1
```

But if there are possibilities of having more courses with same Fees, try this following-

```
SELECT * FROM COURSE
WHERE Fees = 
(
    SELECT MIN(Fees)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Fees
        FROM Course
        ORDER BY Fees DESC
        LIMIT 2
    )A
)
```

Comment: Doesn't deal with " If there are more than two courses then sort it by using Course ID"

Comment: how outer query selects second max salary if you do not do `order by fees desc` ?

Comment: I have checked the script again with no Syntax issue. May be you are missing some part of the script while copy. @Atishay

Comment: @zealous It will return the second max value if we don not apply ORDER on the Outer query. As default it will apply a ASC ordering and the MIN value will on top and We need the MIN value from MAX 2 selected from the Inner query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from courses where fee = (
    select max(fee) from courses where fee <
        (select max(fee) from courses)
)
order by courseid;
```

Comment: if there are two courses with same second maximum fees i need to select both

Comment: It selects everything with the 2nd highest fee.

Comment: @Atishay, this is the only query that follows the instructions. It returns multiple rows when the are ties also.

Answer (score 0):

this should work using `dense_rank()`, you can take a look here 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8c73/4

```
select
  course_id,
  course_name,
  fees
from
(    select
      *,
      dense_rank() over (order by fees) as rnk
   from courses
) t
where rnk = 2
```

Comment: this is working for only one value. if there are two courses with same second maximum fees i need to select both

Comment: If my answer seems correct then please update accept it as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select courseid,coursename
from 
  course
where fees = (
    select max(fees) 
    from 
      course 
    where fees < (
        select max(fees) from course
    )
)
order by courseid asc;
```

This will work

Comment: please add some explanation or logic to your answers so that others understand it

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select course.courseid,course.coursename from course where 
         fees > (select max(fees) from course where fees < (select max (fees) from course
         where fees not in (select max(fees) from course))) AND fees!=(select max(fees) from course)
         order by courseid;
```

Comment: Use `code` format like this for codes. for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

```
select courseid, coursename from course where fees = (select max(fees) from
(select fees from course where fees < (select max(fees) from course)))
order by courseid;
```

This works and passes the test cases.